# Gem Development Workflow

Tags: ruby, unix, rubygems, workflow

I'm working on a fork of someone's gem that is a command line utility. Here's a general overview of the directory structure:

```
bin/
bin/foo

lib/
lib/foo.rb
lib/foo/bar.rb (etc)
```

To test it, I normally do something like this:

```
cd bin/
./foo <args>
```

But I want to be able to use it from any directory (like it would be once installed). My question is if it's possible to achieve this without installing the gem on my system each time.

My first attempt at this was to create a symbolic link to the foo script that was on my PATH, but this messes with the `require 'foo'` line in the script since `File.dirname(__FILE__)` now refers to wherever the symbolic link was created.

Is there a common way of doing this?

(Oh, and here's the relevant lines from the `foo` script)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

$LOAD_PATH.unshift File.expand_path(File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/../lib')
require 'rubygems'
require 'foo'
```

(EDIT)

I'm aware of the normal ways of testing a library (ie `rake test`, etc)--I'm specifically interested in using the script from any directory without reinstalling the gem with every change (if possible).

Comment: For testing you have rspec/test::unit/cucumber/etc. once those tests are "green", install the gem and test it your self. If you insist on your way, you could add the location of the file to your path as opposed to the symbolic link.

Comment: (see comment on Denis's answer)

Comment: @mportiz08 did you every find a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

In almost every gem I've looked into, there is a rakefile of some sort. In which case you go to the root of the gem, and go:

```
rake test
```

For a list of tasks, use:

```
rake -T
```

(This assumes you have [rake](https://github.com/jimweirich/rake) installed in the first place, obviously: `gem install rake` if not.)

Also, many a gem also features a gemfile. In this case you can use [bundler](http://gembundler.com/) to install applicable dependencies (in particular, test suites and development-related gems).

Comment: I'm familiar with Rake and Bundler, but I'm not interested in running unit tests--I'm after the actual use of the command line script--specifically, how to use it from any directory without doing a gem install after incremental changes (if possible).